# Fixed point bisected by a chord.

Tags: geometry

> Circle $O$ has radius $5$ and $BC=6$. Point $A$ is on major arc $BC$ such that there is only one point $D$ such that $AD$ is bisected by $BC$. Find $\sin{\angle{AOB}}$.
>   https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/ebuxcbbk

Since $O$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $AD, OE$ is perpendicular to $AD$. In other words, $BC$ is tangent to the circle with center $M$ and radius $MA$ if $M$ is the midpoint of $AO$.  By PoP on $X$, we get $OX=4$ and $DX=1$. Any ideas?

Comment: If the second part is referencing the Geogebra link, you should make that clear. Can you explain why "OE is perpendicular to BC"? I think you mean "OE is perpendicular to AD". Also, for the subsequant bit, it might be better to define M first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your question, construct a circle with $OA$ as a diameter, and let $M$ be the centre. Your earlier work deduced that $BC$ is a tangent of this smaller circle, and let $E$ be the point of tangency.

Let $N$ be the midpoint of chord $BC$. The distance between $O$ and chord $BC$, is

$$ON = \sqrt{OB^2 - \left(\frac{BC}{2}\right)^2}= \sqrt{5^2 - 3^2} = 4$$

Then there is a right-angled trapezium $OMEN$, with $ME\perp NE$ and $NE\perp ON$. Recall that $OM = ME = 2.5$ as radii of the smaller circle, and $ON = 4$, so

$$NE = \sqrt{OM^2 - (ON-ME)^2} = \sqrt{2.5^2 - 1.5^2} = 2$$

From here, there are two symmetrical cases, depending on whether $A$ is closer to $B$ or closer to $C$.

---

If $A$ is closer to $B$, then $E$ is also closer to $B$ than to $C$. Consider the length of $CE$,

$$CE = CN + NE = 3 + 2 = 5 = OC$$

Since $CE$ is a tangent to the smaller circle, and $O$ and $E$ are different points on the smaller circle, $OC$ is also a tangent to the smaller circle, and so

$$OC\perp OA$$

Then by dividing $\angle AOC = 90^\circ$,

$$\begin{align*}
\angle AOB + \angle BOC &= 90^\circ\\
\sin \angle AOB &= \sin \left(90^\circ - \angle BOC\right)\\
&= \cos \angle BOC\\
&= \frac{OB^2 + OC^2 - BC^2}{2 OB\cdot OC}\\
&= \frac{5^2 + 5^2 - 6^2}{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5}\\
&= \frac{7}{25}
\end{align*}$$

---

If $A$ is closer to $C$, then $E$ is also closer to $C$ than to $B$, then by the similar reason,

$$BE = BN + NE = 3+2 = 5 = OB$$

And so, in additional to $BE$, $OB$ is a (different) tangent to the smaller circle. Then $OB\perp OA$ and

$$\sin \angle AOB = 1$$